# Converting Matlab to Python, errors with arrays and for loops

Tags: python, matlab, indices

I am pretty new to programming so be patient with me lol. I am trying to convert an example code of matlab to python but I am having trouble with arrays in for loops and keep getting index errors.

Here is the given MatLab Code:

```
clear all
close all
clc
m=100; %kg 
k=1000; %N/m
c=25;
v0=0;
x0=0;
dt=0.0005;
F=1000; % N the mag of input force
f0=F/m;
w=2.5; %rad/sec input frequency 
t=0:dt:10;
wn=(k/m)^0.5;% rad/sec natural frequency 
ze=c/(2*(k*m)^0.5);
A=[0 1; -wn^2 -2*ze*wn];
X0=[x0;v0]; %intial conditions 
for i=1:length(t)
    X(:,i)=X0;
    Finput=[0;f0*cos(w*t(i))];
    X0=X0+A*X0*dt+dt*Finput;
end
figure,plot(t,X(1,:));
title('Displacement vs tiem')
xlabel('time (second)')
ylabel('Displacement')
grid on
figure,plot(t,X(2,:),'r');
xlabel('time (second)')
ylabel('Velocity')
```

My code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#constants
k=1000
m=100
v0=0.0
x0=0.0
f=1000
c=25

f0 = f/m
wn = np.sqrt(k/m)
w = wn*2
ze =c/(2*(k*m)**0.5)

A = np.array([[0.0,1.0],[-wn**2,-2*ze*wn]])
X0= np.array([x0,v0])
dt = 0.01
t = np.arange(0, 2.5, dt) #get values between -10 and 10 with 0.01 step and set to y

for i in range (len(t)):
             print(X0)
             X0[:,i]=X0 #error
             print(X0)
             Finput = np.array([0.0,(f0*np.cos(w*dt*i))])

             X0 = X0 + A*dt*X0+dt*Finput

plt.plot(t, X0[0,:])
plt.plot(t, X0[1,:])
plt.show()
```

I keep getting an "IndexError: too many indices for array" for the X0[:,i]=X0 part in my for loop and am struggling to figure out why.

Many Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

In Matlab code, `X(:,i)=X0;` assigns X0 to ith column of **X**. But your python `X0[:,i]=X0 #error` is assiging X0 to **X0** ith column.

Comment: Actually, `X0` to `X0` *row*. Column major, row major.

Answer (score 1):

The first time MATLAB runs the line

```
    X(:,i)=X0;
```

it creates a *new variable* `X` whose `i`'th column is equal to `X0`. In your code `i` is 1 when this happens but if `i` were > 1, MATLAB would initialise columns 1...i-1 with zeroes. After the loop is done, the code plots the data from the matrix `X`.

You have mistakenly translated this as `X0[:,i]=X0` in your Python code, which gives an error because you're trying to assign to `X0` as if it were a two-dimensional array when it's only one-dimensional.

Python and numpy don't automatically create and grow arrays when you assign to a subarray in the way that MATLAB does, so in Python you need to create the array `X` before the loop then either `resize` the array each time before you assign to the next column of it, or just initialise it with the right size when you create it - since you know how big it's going to be, i.e. `len(t)`, do the latter - you can use `np.zeros` for this.

Also, in the Python code as you have posted it the line `X0 = X0 + A*dt*X0+dt*Finput` is *outside* the loop because the previous line has no indentation - Python should raise an `IndentationError` for this though. Conventionally you should use four spaces for each level of indentation.

After the loop in the Python code you want to plot the contents of `X`, not `X0`.